# Bipolar Transistor H Bridge - low side NPN transistors slow to turn off

Tags: h-bridge, inverter, bipolar

I've been trying to build an H-Bridge from bipolar transistors. Here are my parts for the schematic below

- Q1, Q2 - A1694
- Q3, Q4 - C4467
- Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8 - 2N5551
- R2, R3 - 100 ohm
- R5, R6 - 50 ohm
- R9, R7, R10, R8 - 1000 ohm
- R12 - 10 ohm
- R11 - 1000 ohm
- R13, R14, R15, R16 - 22K ohm

`CLK2` is the inverse of `CLK1`. Both clocks are provided by a attiny84, so the maximum allowable current is 40 mA per pin.

The resistor `R11` is my "load". The resistor `R12` is so I do not blow up the power transistors.

Here are datasheets for the power transistors. They were "free" in so much as they've been in my junk box for years. I tested them each individually and they seem to be fine. They exhibit very high gain compared to a power transistor like a 2N3055.

http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sa1694_ds_en.pdf

http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sc4467_ds_en.pdf

`R13-R16` are there to help the transistors `Q1-Q4` turn off. The transistors `Q5-Q8` do not need such transistors because the output of the attiny84 is driven low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flMYnb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I power things on I see a current from the 12 volt supply of 0.897 A. Obviously, something is wrong.

This is what I see when I measure across my "load" `R11`
[image]

This is my two clocks, which are the inverse of each other
[image]

This is the voltage at the base of `Q3` and `Q4`. I call this the "low-side"
[image]

This is the voltage at the base of `Q1` and `Q2`. I call this the "high- side"
[image]

The voltage at the base of each low-side transistor seems to be incredibly noisy, but at least is 1 time unit out of phase with each other.

The voltage at the base of the high-side transistor does not make sense to me at all. There is no time unit shift at all. They seem to be turning on together. This makes sense if you look at the strange waveform I measured across `R11`.

I've checked the voltage at the base of `Q5`, `Q6`, `Q8`, and `Q7` as well. They make sense, in that they are not noisy and are one time unit out of phase with each other.

Did I make an elementary mistake in the design of this circuit, or is my problem somewhere in my assembly? Is there anything else I can measure with my oscilloscope to help troubleshoot this circuit?

Update:

As was pointed out, there should be dead time between my clocks. I have set the dead time to 5 microseconds.

I also should mention that each transistor has a 1N4007 across it "backwards" to protect against any reverse current.

Here are my clocks:

[image]

Here is the rising edge of one clock and the falling edge of another:

[image]

Here is the base of Q5 & Q1, notice the voltage scales are different:

[image]

Here is the base of Q6 & Q2, notice the voltage scales are different:

[image]

When the base of Q5 is driven to a high voltage the transistor should saturate. The voltage at the base of Q1 should drop. It does, but seems to come back up to a lower value fairly quickly, then the voltage on the base of Q1 comes back up  about 1/2 way before the voltage drops off to Q1. I'm really baffled by this.

Update:

As some contributors pointed out, my circuit had noise in it which did not have an explanation. My 5 volt power supply is faulty, it injects noise into my circuit. I found a 5 volt 2 amp power supply and used it instead.

I have narrowed down my problem to **slow NPN transistor turn off**. I measured the base of Q3 and R6. My limited understanding of these transistors is that the base should have a threshold voltage of approximately 600 mV. A voltage below this is an "off" state and above this is a "on" state. It is more complex than what I am stating due to transistor gain and the current in the base of course. Is measuring the base voltage a good method for determining the state of the transistor?

[image]

As you can see, the voltage at R6 drops when the transistor Q7 comes on. The voltage at Q3 of course comes up and the transistor is on at this point. The voltage at R6 goes back up when the Q7 is off. But the base of the transistor stays at approximately 600 mV for another 30 microseconds or so. Then it tapers down.

R5 & Q4 look identical. So both NPN transistors behave the same.

I added a 100 ohm emitter-collector resistor across Q3. The turn off time is the same, with the difference that voltage drops from 600 millivolts to zero in less than 10 microseconds **when it finally turns off*. The NPN transistor is still on too long.

Here are the bases of one of the high side pairs, Q5 & Q1.

[image]

The blue line is the base voltage of Q5 and the yellow is the base of Q1. I still do not completely understand what is going on with this side of the circuit. Between transitions of Q5's base voltage, there is always a 30 microsecond delay in the transitions of the base of Q1. This agrees with the time I identified in which the NPN transistor is on too long. For some period of time, my 12 volt supply is shorted. But R12 protects my circuit and the voltage across the H-Bridge drops to nearly zero.

At this point I think solving the slow turn off of the NPN transistors is the first priority. Are there any test circuits I can use on the NPN transistors in isolation?

Comment: I notice that you have no dead-band. Those NPN transistors take only 130 nanoseconds to turn on, but 3800 nanoseconds to turn off (assuming that they reach saturation, which they should). That means that you will have over 3.5 microseconds of shoot-through, which, because of R12, will suck your 12 volts to almost nothing.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm wrong above. I notice that your switching frequency is real low, so maybe there is dead-band, and I just can't see it on the scope picture. But you did say that the two drive signals were inverses of each other, which would imply that there is no dead-band. With the scope, try measuring the voltage drop across R12 to get an idea of what the current draw from the 12 volt supply looks like.

Comment: There is approximately 2.5 microseconds of dead time between switching.

Comment: OK, 2.5 will accommodate the PNP transistors, but is less than the storage time of the NPN transistors. The dead-time should be at least 4 microseconds, but I don't think that is the problem. After only a microsecond of shoot-through, the circuit should have recovered within the following 50 microseconds.

Comment: I think I will be more generous with the dead time and try again. Otherwise my circuit seems logical however?

Comment: What is the purpose of R5 and R6?

Comment: R5 and R6 limit the current seen in the base of Q3 and Q4. Also, I put a complete list of my components in the description.

Comment: Yes, I finally noticed that. Why didn't you put the values right in the schematic? You actually had to go to some trouble to suppress them.

Comment: I changed to use 5 microseconds of dead time. There is no change in the behavior. I think I have an incorrect assembly or a bad component somewhere.

Comment: It does seem logical - The layout looks like it should work, although I haven't done all of the calculations. One thing doesn't seem logical - Why are you still using bipolar transistors in an H-bridge? Below about 40 amps, I would use MosFETs, and above that I would use IGBTs. Both are easier to design with (but I'm not saying that you don't have a good reason).

Comment: The transistors were free, and I've blown up enough gates on MOSFETs for the time being. This circuit won't have much practical use but I could use it to test random inductors I salvage from various power supplies.

Comment: I just read your update, and I'm baffled as well. Q1 and Q2 make no sense. Both Q5 and Q1, as well as Q6 and Q2, have close to fifty percent duty-cycles, but  while Q5 and Q6 have the expected 10kHz frequency, Q1 and Q2 have twice that frequency (and they're driven by Q5 and Q6). It almost seems like your scope is playing tricks on you.

Comment: I see a lot of noise spikes on the signal lines at both high and low levels. Is there proper power supply bypassing with capacitors?

Comment: I have a 10000 pF ceramic capacitor and a 22 uF electrolytic capacitor on the pins of the microcontroller.

Comment: @Mark I updated again. The low-side transistors are not turning off.